# Jquery tabs don't remember last open tab on new page load

Tags: jquery, tabs, default

I'm using JS for some simple Jquery tabs, which I use as a main vertical navigation bar on my website in development.

I have two main tabs, 'tab 1' (left hand side) and 'tab 2' (right hand side). 
On each of these tabs there are sub links that link to various pages of the website.

So my problem is that whenever I click on a link from 'tab 2', when that new page loads, the navigation bar with revert to 'tab 1' as default.

I would like it so that any links I click on from 'tab 2', have the navigation bar defaulting to that 'tab 2' on load.

My JS is here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".tab-content").hide();                           
$("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();    
$(".tab-content:first").show();                     
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {                  
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");          
    $(this).addClass("active");                     
    $(".tab-content").hide();                       
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
    $(activeTab).fadeIn();                          
    return false;
});});
```

Any help would be gratefully recieved.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!-- START TABS -->

            <div class="tabbz">
                <ul class="tabs">
                    <li><a href="#tab1">サービス内容</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#tab2">ご利用案内</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-container">
                    <div id="tab1" class="tab-content">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                            <a href="/a.php">転送サービス</a>                                
                            <a href="/b.php">お買い物サービス</a>   
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="/b1.php">卸売・仕入れサポート</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/b2.php">国際展示会サポート</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div id="tab2" class="tab-content">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/c.php">ご利用ガイド</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="/c1.php">個人輸入とは</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/c2.php">サービスの流れ</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/d.php">料金ガイド</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="/d1.php">手数料について</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/d2.php">換算レート</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>                               
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Not sure if jquery tabs support this, but bootstrap tabs can each be a seperate href, and your href's could all be the same except have a different anchor on the end ".../url#activeTabId".  Clicking a link where the beforeHasbang# part is the same doesn't cause navigation, but will change the URL in the address bar, so refreshing will preserve the #activeTabId part of the URL and allow your javascript to inspect in docuement.ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change this line

```
$("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();
```

to

```
$("ul.tabs li.active").show();
```

and in your html just add **class="active"** to the li

```
<li class="active">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have replaced the JS line to the one you commented, and also set the '#tab2' to be active (you can see in the HTML code i've added in the original question). The page tab does indeed default to tab2 when loading this page, however the content inside the tab is still that of tab1, until I click on tab2 again. I hope its a simple fix :)

Comment: you will need to remove this line in the js **$(".tab-content:first").show();** and replace it with **var activeTab = $('ul.tabs').find('li.active').find('a').attr("href"); $(activeTab).show();**

Answer (score 1):

Well, a new page load happens, so the tabs reinitialize from scratch. You're going to have to pass the selected tab between pages somehow - either in the URL as a fragment or parameter, or in a cookie, and then read the value back and use it when you initialize the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

on each page, you can add some attribute or something that uniquely identifies that page, like `<body id="contact">`.

Alter your js where it says to add the active class based on the body id

```
  $("ul.tabs li."+$('body').attr('id')).addClass("active").show();
```